# In safari, body with position: fixed returns scrollLeft 0

Tags: javascript, safari

In safari body with position: fixed always return zero of `document.body.scrollLeft`. In chrome and other browsers all OK.

How i can get scroll position in safari?

Try to scroll and get `document.body.scrollLeft` in safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="width: 3000px; display: inline-block; height: 100px; border-left-width: 100px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: red;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question? I don't read any questions here.

Comment: @Thomas updated.
How i can get scroll position in safari?